# Fazer alert depois do hide() de um loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou começando uns estudos com JQuery, e estou tendo um problema.

estou fazendo uma pagina de login e eu fiz um loading. Este loading só aperece depois quando é feito o submit, ou seja...

```
$('#form-login').submit(function () {
    $('.wait').show();
});
```

e eu uso também

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.wait').hide();
});
```

porém eu envio uns dados por parametro nesta pagina, e pego para fazer um alert, da seguinte maneira:

```
if (mensagem == 1) {
    alert("alerta 1");
} else if (mensagem == 2) {
    alert("alerta 2");
}
```

porém eu precisava que quando este alerta fosse aparecer, ele removesse esse loading que estava aparecendo.

Já tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
if (mensagem == 1) {
    $('.wait').hide();
    alert("alerta 1");
} else if (mensagem == 2) {
    $('.wait').hide();
    alert("alerta 2");
}
```

e não deu certo, o loading continua aparecendo junto com o alerta.

OBS: "mensagem" é a variavel que recebe o parametro que é passado.

**EDIT:** Vou deixar meu código jquery a seguir.

```
$(document).ready(function () { //Função que será realizada quando carregar a página
    $('.wait').hide();
    //Pega o valor dos parametros da URL
    var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
            sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
            sParameterName,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
            sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

            if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
            }
        }
    };

    var mensagem = getUrlParameter('msg'); //Passa o valor do parâmetro da URL para a variável 'mensagem'

    //Remove o parâmetro da URL
    var uri = window.location.toString();
    if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
        var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
    }

    //Faz o alerta de verificação
    if (mensagem == 1) {
        alert("Alerta 1");
    } else if (mensagem == 2) {
        alert("Alerta 2");
    } 

    //Verifica os espaços em branco ou vazios ao clicar no botão "Acessar"
    $("#enter").on("click", function () {
        $("[required]", $(this).closest("form")).filter(function (i, e) {
            return !$(e).val().trim();
        }).val('');

        $("#numeroSerie").val($("#numeroSerie").val().trim());
        $("#user").val($("#user").val().trim());
        $("#pass").val($("#pass").val().trim());
    });

    //Cria a mensagem de carregamento (Loading)
    $('#form-login').submit(function () {
        $('.wait').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: *"Fazer alert depois de"*, de que? Pf edite o titulo da sua pergunta

Comment: está alterado Ricardo, obrigado

Comment: O que o submit tem a ver com os if's?

Comment: @Sam, estou apenas mostrando meu código, mostrei o submit, pois é la que eu coloco o show() do loading

Comment: @RicardoPontual, peço desculpas, esqueci de te marcar

Comment: Esses if's ficam dentro do submit? Desculpe mas não está dando pra saber o funcionamento disso. Onde ficam esses if's? Coloque o código completo como vc fez, e não em partes.

Comment: Não há nada de errado com esse código, mas como você mencionou um submit, suspeito que esse erro possa estar sendo causado devido a natureza assíncrona das requisições. Talvez tenha sido por isso que o Sam perguntou sobre o submit. Só com o código postado não da para saber o que está causando o erro, seria melhor se você postasse todo o fluxo do código.

Comment: @Sam, deixei o codigo jquery na pergunta

Comment: Obrigado @user140828, deixei o código na questão

Comment: Em vez de esconder o loading no JavaScript, vc deveria colocar no seu CSS: `.wait{ display: none; }`

Comment: Meu Deus, não acredito que era apenas isso... funcionou, muito obrigado, mas poderia me detalhar mais de o porque funcionou com css e não funciona com esta função do jquery?

Comment: O alert trava o navegador, e só libera alterações na página quando vc fecha ele.

Comment: Entendi, deixei a resposta da questão publicada, para outras pessoas que tiverem a mesma dúvida, conseguirem encontrar mais facilmente. Obrigado. @Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só para deixar respondido aqui qual foi a solução, deixada pelo @Sam nos comentários, é a seguinte...

Em vez de esconder o loading no JavaScript, deveria ser usado o CSS:

```
.wait{ display: none; }
```

Funcionou perfeitamente, o loading foi retirado na hora correta.